# Color of buttons in TabView

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am specifically using the "non-filled" SF symbols in my code, however the symbols are still filled regardless of what I do.

I am sure that it is because of one of the background/foreground color presets in the init method, but I cannot figure out which one.

For some reason I also cannot change the size of the SF Symbol - I set the scale to large but it does not do anything.

Any help is appreciated.

```
struct tabViewErchis: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
        
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
        
        TabView() {
            temp()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "globe.americas.fill")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        

                    
                }
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bag")
                        

                    
                }
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square")

                    
                }
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Filled SF Symbols in Menu Bar]

Comment: Is the issue the tab items being white? Or is the issue the selected tab item being blue?

Comment: The issue is that the SF symbol I chose is the one that is not filled - for instance the second "bag" icon should not be filled with white, it should just show the bag outline.

Comment: But yeah - I also want the selected tab item should not be blue

Comment: Why does such basic functionality seem so esoteric - I fell like modifying something as simple as a button color should not be this complicated

Comment: Not basic, but the reason is simple - SwiftUI is still in youth.