# Making TabView Icons a specific color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a tab bar whose icons I am trying to make white, however despite the fact that I am specifying the color, the icons remain grey for some reasons (despite me never actually setting them to grey).

[image]

The code is shown below -

```
struct tabViewUnique: View {
    init() {
        
        
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
                                                   
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
        
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView() {
            temp()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "globe.americas.fill")
                }
            
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bag")
                    
                }
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                }
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                }
        }.accentColor(.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: you have already asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326038/color-of-buttons-in-tabview

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need to create custom appearance instead work with default one

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
```

[Complete test module in project](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTabViewBarAppearance.swift)